# fetch() call always returns promise I can't get anything from

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have what I believe to be a timing issue in my async code.  I *believe* but can't 100% confirm that the API I am calling has not yet returned the result when the next step is called.  All of my code works if I pass a simple *myJSON = `some legit JSON here`* and use that in *JSON.parse(myJSON)*, etc.  However a fetch response does NOT work the same.  I have tried using both async/await and .then() syntax with the same result.

All I really want out of this execution is a string containing some JSON.  Promises and all that just confuse me, as many times as I've tried to understand.  I don't want to do ANYTHING else until I get a response, but apparently you can't run fetch() synchronously - and wrapper "workarounds" to that don't do anything to help my understanding of the async functionality any better.

.then() chain approach

```js
let x;

const response = fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=hello&maxResults=1")
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((response) => x = response);

console.log("THIS IS RESPONSE...");
console.log(response); // undefined

console.log("THIS IS X...");
console.log(x); // undefined
```

async/await

```
// the function this lives in is an async function
const response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=hello&maxResults=1",
      { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } });
let data = await response.json();

console.log("THIS IS DATA...");
console.log(data); // undefined
```

How do I just get the JSON response text?

Comment: With the `.then` approach, put your console.log (or whatever code needs to use the `response`) inside the final `.then` callback. The second code looks fine, assuming the console.logs are in the same async function as the rest of it.

Comment: The first `console.log(response)` should *not* be `undefined`, it should be a promise object.

Comment: if `console.log(data); // undefined` then the server response is probably nothing - we can't see your server, so, that's something you'll need to check - what is `queryString`?

Comment: @PratikPrakashBindage Your first comment makes total sense.  I do struggle to understand async in general.  I do understand that the fetch may not be complete yet, but how (and **why**) do I want to use async here at all?  Isn't fetch async only anyway, meaning I **must** use await?  Why is it that every example I see of fetch uses async?

Comment: Also, your comment with the code snippet, when I debug line by line with breakpoints at each of the console.log() statements and at the fetch() line, the fetch line executes, and completely skips over the skips everything else.  The queryString value is `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=hello&maxResults=1` if you want to test it, it's valid.  Chrome dev tools says it returns in 265ms.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think `response.json()` ever returns (a promise for) `undefined`

Comment: @Bergi - unless it's `"undefined"` - though, now that the URL has been added, probably not in this case

Comment: This code you show does _not_ in fact produce the output you claim. Which suggests your _actual_ code is different.